Do the poor have any power in this world?
It seems to me that a lot of government policy is determined on the premise that the poor are responsible for the social and economic problems in the world.
Do the poor have power and thus are capable of determining the outcomes of this world, or do the rich have the power?
I was wondering about a phillosopical perspective upon this as in what makes the poor, poor, and such are they responsible for their poverty or are they powerless to prevent it?

not having any money is what makes poor poor, i'm afraid this question has nothing to do with philosophy

@DennisKozevnikoff I've got two words for  you  Flippant and Disrespectful!!

@andrós Thanks for your referral.

Well, the proletariat has nothing to loose but its chains, you know...


what makes the poor, poor

The global questions about our reality are best understood when we review the energy fueling that progress in human society.
When we try to imagine the purpose of this reality and the means that make it change and evolve, we can understand the place of 'poor' people in the engine of progress.
Why did people's ancestors climb down from the trees? Why do people come out of the caves? Why did the first civilizations create opportunities to have professionals and specialists whose main purpose was to use their brains?
This is all the result of endorphins driving human desires and in turn driving the world to some final goal (Hegel).
The energy generated by 'poor' who want to be 'rich' is an important part of the engine of progress.

Black Elk was a native American, a Lakota holy man, who fought in the Indian Wars against the United States government. He could not read or write, but he spoke to a couple of poets. Those poets produced two books from his spoken words: Black Elk Speaks and The Sacred Pipe. In The Sacred Pipe there is a ritual called Keeping the Soul. This is a Lakota ritual for consecrating the memories of a dead relative. Black Elk describes it as a ritual that required the help of a holy man and many economic resources. He said this ritual was more difficult on the poor who had fewer resources.
When Black Elk describes the conflict between the Lakota and Wasichu (invading Western culture), he says, "Once we were happy in our own land. The two-leggeds and four-leggeds lived together as relatives, and there was plenty for them and for us. But then up in the Black Hills the Wasichu found much of the little yellow metal which they worship and it makes them crazy." The way I interpret this statement is as follows. In the Lakota culture the children did not learn to desire money via the psychological mechanism that Rene Girard calls Mimetic Desire. The Lakota parents did not value, earn, spend, or use gold money so the Lakota children did not comprehend why the Wasichu would cause so much conflict due to their appetite to own, spend, or use gold as money. To a person who values life for its own sake the destruction of life for the love of money is just crazy!
Jesus said the poor will always be with us. This seems to be a limitation in the way we produce and distribute goods, services, and social prestige in a human culture. I have thought a great deal about how to improve the welfare of the poor and middle class in the context of political-economic relations. The legal system in capitalism allows for some children to inherit moderate to vast wealth while other children are educated under public policy and then forced to work and typically incur debt to consume resources from the mix of wages and debt. In terms of investment, production, and distribution of goods political-economic growth is a positive sum game. But the distribution of power in society might be more of a zero-sum game similar to social hierarchy in the societies of so-called lower apes.
The author of the book of James argues that Christians should become like God who gives generously and ungrudgingly to all. The Catholic priests and nuns take vows of poverty and charity. In a society that values those character traits one might gain prestige by taking less from the production of society so others might have more. But meritocracy does not inherently value such values. The rich are worshipped in part because they resemble the parents or adults in early life, they have money but the child is poor, they have power but the child has submissive or subordinate roles; and in part we think the rich merit their wealth, or we have contempt for their social advantages. It is complex ape psychology.

You do realise that the Catholic church is obscenely rich and quite firmly insists that this will remain that way, with higher-ups profiting a lot, do you? Also, how does all this offer any real answer to the question, which is explicitly on whether there is a necessity for money if one wants to have power?

@PhilipKlöcking - Black Elk lived in a culture of social power but without money. The concept of rich and poor existed in his mind. I am aware that the Vatican, wealthy households, governments, or Museums, tend to own and possess the so-called priceless works of art, which of course sell for a price! A young man once challenged me asking why the Vatican did not sell its priceless works of art and give to the poor! I told him it would only transfer possession of those works of art to another party in society and the one-time gift to the poor would not eradicate structural causes of poverty.
